# How can I use a div element to redirect with MVC htmlhelper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper, actionlink

I have a bunch of div elements that look like this at the moment:

```
<div  onclick="window.open('Technology','mywindow');" class="grid" id="technology">                    
     <p class="category-title">Technology</p>        
</div>
```

I would like to get rid of the window.open and instead use MVC htmlhelper like actionlink to redirect users when they click on the div element. How can I do that?

Comment: ActionLink will return an anchor tag. Are you ok. with this ?

Answer (score 5):

The correct way to handle this is with a simple anchor tag.

Replace "myAction" and "myController" with the location you want to redirect the user to.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("myAction", "myController")">
    <div class="grid" id="technology">                    
         <p class="category-title">Technology</p>        
    </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

`ActionLink` will return an `anchor` tag. What you can do is, you can assign the URL to the attribute of div via `@Url.Action()`. Then in `JavaScript` you can grab this URL and open a new window.

```
<div data-action ="@Url.Action("Text", "ActionName")">                    
     <p class="category-title">Technology</p>        
</div>
```

And in jQuery

```
$('div').click(function () {
    var url = $(this).attr('data-action');

    if(url !== undefined)
        window.location.href = url;    
});
```

Alternatively in pure JS,

```
document.document.getElementsByTagName('div').onclick = function(e) {

     var url = this.getAttribute('data-action')

     if(url !== null)
         window.location.href = url;  
}
```

This way, all `divs` having the `data-action` attribute will redirect to new page.

Comment: Is it possible to skip the jquery? also I want to get rid of the window.open, I dont want a new window

Comment: @Rohander updated my answer. I assumed you want in pure JS, when you said "can we skip jQuery" :). If you do not want to use either, then you should restructure your html and use anchor tags instead of divs.